# How can I see when my first win of the day bonus is available?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that, on the game summary screen, I can see when my first win of the day bonus is available.  Is there a way to see that countdown that doesn't involve playing an entire game?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but I almost always leave my LoL client on the game summary when I finish playing.  When I come back, I know exactly how long until my bonus is up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the Hecarim patch, this functionality has been added:

> Added first win of the day status to the summoner profile.

To access it, simply click the tab to view your profile. On the main screen where you can see your various rankings, the main banner will indicate the status of the daily bonus on the lower right.

[image]

Sources: [Hecarim Patch Notes  - Riot Games](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/hecarim-patch-notes) & [V1.0.0.138 Patch Notes - League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.138#PvP.net)

Comment: You can always do one dominon Co-OP (8min ~ 10min) to get your First win.

Comment: Thank goodness this has been added.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: I'm happy I could help ^.^

Comment: New client has it under "profile", "overview" then it's the third icon from the left under your name.  However, at this time it doesn't show you the exact time, just the number of hours, rounded up.